# Improper integral calculation and nature

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, equivalence-relations, riemann-sum

I would like to know how to calculate this integral n check its nature :

$$
A= \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{1+t^{2}} dt  .
$$
I think I figured it out , we can do it with Equivalence like this (since it is positive):
$$
\frac{e^{-t}}{1+t^{2}}   \leq   \frac{1}{1+t^{2}}  And  \frac{1}{1+t^{2}} \simeq \frac{1}{t^{2}}
$$

Now I know $$ \frac{e^{-t}}{1+t^{2}} $$ is positive n tends to $0$ so the nature of $A$ is the nature of :
$$ \Sigma  \frac{e^{-t}}{1+t^{2}} \simeq \Sigma \frac{1}{t^{2}}$$ wich we know converges (the Riemann serie)

Comment: Judging by the output on WolframAlpha I think this problem is a bit tough. In particular, the answer involves the exponential integral $Ei$. Perhaps the problem is incorrectly stated?

Comment: I believe he's studying convergence, not the actual answer to the integral.